# I want a control for Hotel room booking status to show in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am planing to show hotel room booking status as a color effect. See the image. At want control I want to use?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, this is WPF... you could use just about any control that you want to do that. Ok so I'm exaggerating a bit, but it really is *your* choice. You should use whatever you're comfortable with. However, if I had to design a UI that looked like your image, I'd probably either go with a `ListBox` or a `DataGrid` with a fairly high level of customisation.

If I were to use a `DataGrid`, the day names could be the column headers and the room names could be the row headers. You'd also need to use some sort of custom `ColorConverter` class to colour the cell data in the cells.

Using a `ListBox`, I'd create a `DataTemplate` to apply to the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property that would contain the whole row including the room name. Of course, this would mean that you'd need to structure your data differently to include the name of each room. With a known number of days/columns, you could just use a `Grid` in the `DataTemplate` with the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property set to `True` to keep the columns of each item aligned.

Good luck and have fun with that... it seems like an interesting project.

Comment: thank you sir. I will try this in grid. If I face any trouble will write here.